# C arrays - Incorrect response to wrong input?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I've got an assingment for a Programming course (beginner level) and the only thing I couldn't get right (according to the teacher at least) was how one of the functions handled wrong input. Atm it looks like this:

```
void Modify(int id[], char str[100][30], int kredit[], int count)
{
    system("cls");
    int Search_value;
    bool flag = false;
    printf("Enter ID to be modified (1-100):: ");
    scanf("%d", &Search_value);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (id[i] == Search_value)
        {
            printf("Old record\n");
            printf("ID :: %d \n", id[i]);
            printf("Name :: %s \n", str[i]);
            printf("Kredit :: %d\n", kredit[i]);
            printf("New record\n");
            printf("Name :: ");
            scanf("%s",str[i]);
            printf("Kredit :: ");
            scanf("%d", &kredit[i]);
            printf("New data saved\n");
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    if (flag == false)
    {
        printf("ID not found\n");
    }
    system("pause");
```

Part of the task describing how Modify should be done:

**c)    Modify data**

- do search and display according to point b) (different function ->
  Search_value)
- if the record is found, ask for the new data
- ID can't be modified!
- save the modified record into the arrays, overwriting the old one

Compiles and runs without any problem whatsoever. Or at least I haven't noticed. I can add more of the code if needed of course.

Comment: Whats the question? What did your teacher say is the correct answer? What do you think is the correct answer?

Comment: Not really related to the question but this is all very cumbersome, you should check out [how to use struct s in C](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson7.html).

Comment: You don't check the result of `scanf`. If it fails (the user did not enter a number), then `Search_value` will be undefined. (You don't initialize it either.)

Comment: Because `count` indexes `str`, it cannot be larger than 100.

Comment: In `scanf("%s",str[i]);` you don't handle that the string read may be no longer than 29 chars (plus `\0`).

Comment: It my be so that `kredit` does not need to be changed, so not checking whether the user entered a number in `scanf("%d", &kredit[i]);` is valid.

Comment: It is assumed that `count` gives the maximum used element of all arrays passed. No checks are required. (Note: this is design. Design could equally well dictate the value must be checked against some constant or checked to be `>= 0`.)

Comment: @George It was specified that use of struct is not allowed in this task, but thanks for the heads up! For the rest, thanks for specifying. Guess I was trying too hard to read between the lines while the problem was so simple

Answer (score 2):

Dealing with errors means thinking about things that could go wrong. After a quick look in your program,

What happens if I input a value that is out of the required range?
What happens if count is larger than it should or negative?
What happens if kredit is smaller than it should?
what happens if a string from str does not have a NUL terminator?

And some more of these can be found. In general, you don't have to validate every argument at every function call (although it might help finding bugs during development), but you should definitely validate user input.